# Black holes are not infinitely dense

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, density, escape-velocity

If a black hole is infinitely dense, then therefore its terminal velocity in a determined field of gravity would be greater than the speed of light which is impossible, therefore a blackhole is not infinitely dense.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question.

Comment: What do you think the formula for gravitational “terminal velocity” is?

Answer (score 1):

First you should decide what density you're referring to. If you know the mass of the black hole based on the data you analysed and it's Schwarzschild radius then you got a finite density from well known $\rho = M / V$. Yet if you refer to the density at the center, it's infinite due to singularity having no volume measure.

Comment: As observed from outside, the volume $V$ inside the horizon is zero. Also, the density of a singularity is not infinite, but undefined.